# Non-consistent SSIS error 'Opening a rowset for "%1" failed.' when using COZYROC dataflowtask+

Tags: ssis, cozyroc

In a daily process only sometimes (so far 2 times, more than 15 days apart) it fails with a message "Opening a rowset for "%1" failed." This error happens in a DataFlowTask+ which reads a view and materializes it in a table.

The error usually refers to a problem with the view, but when I execute the view it executes without errors and showing correct number of records and columns. If I execute the SSIS job again, it executes without errors, so it let's me guessing what went wrong as no field is mentioned in the error.

*COZYROC configuration*

[image: COZYROC configuration]

*SSIS Error*

[image: SSIS ERROR]

Comment: Did you found the solution for this one ?

Comment: hi, I am also facing the same issue, if any one has a solution?